# loading angularjs template is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can any one help me why my angular js template (`template1.html`) is not loading while I am including all my angularjs script loading in template1.html itself. You can find the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/92KYIPDsrmSPIzr15noo?p=preview)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#loadBtn').on("click", function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content").load("template1.html");

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: where's your angular code?

Comment: check this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/57GUEzXhQyls5at20Mqs?p=preview

Comment: Karim, I did not understand what was the wrong in my plunker, except https, as reported by others, but even after that I am getting {{testData}} in the view, but your plunker is working fine. Can you please tell what was the wrong in my plunker?

Comment: Karim, just click couple of time on the Load Html button, even your plunker is also resulting {{testData}} and since then it does not display the result, it shows back again {{testData}}.

Comment: @ Madasu K script.js not exist in your plunker.

Comment: you have mixed jquery with angularjs(your template is not compiled), your way is completely wrong.Create a directive and on load, load the template file 'template1.html' which should be ONLY html inside it, and values that get from controller.

Comment: It is mistake on my part while editing,  I have set it up correctly now in the Question section referenced plunker. In both plunkers (yours and mine), if you click the Load Html button multiple times you can notice {{testData}} (error) and "Angular  Data" (correct) appears randomly, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The plunkr is loaded with HTTPS. The jquery version in the plunkr is loaded via HTTP. Chrome blocked it and just changing that to HTTPS, made your code work.

Comment: Even then, I am getting  Angular Js {{testData}}. Angularj data is showing up

Comment: I have updated my plunker.  You can see even now angular data is not appearing in the view. plnkr.co/edit/JTqjTJSpTTvgF6z7zAuv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML index.html include below jquery library file. It solve your problem.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

check this below working example. This will help you

http://plnkr.co/edit/WvTSifg9XhcKI6DZCfoz?p=preview

Comment: @Madasu K check it.

Comment: Even then, I am getting  Angular Js {{testData}}. Angularj data is showing up

Comment: @Madasu K click function not exit in your code. Add that

Comment: Dhaarani, I can't include  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script> in index.html as you have done in your solution. Because we have jquery based project, with nearly 5 modules. Each module we are trying to implement with different framework (angularjs, backbone, etc). So as I shown in my plunker, in index.html we should call template1.html through load during onclick of button  and then all the angularjs related scripts references and the code should go to template1.html.

Comment: @ Madasu K now what you need. check plunker it work fine with angularjs. you need to do same thing in jquery right?